# java replace e replaceAll. ReplaceAll not working

Tags: java, replace, replaceall

I have this exercise. Why not work with replaceAll? I have an error: String index out of range: 1

```
 public class e3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String x="Sessione successiva";
        String nuova=x.replace("i", "!");
        String nuova2=nuova.replace("s", "$");
        String nuova3=nuova2.replace("e", "&");
        System.out.println(nuova3);

            //replaceAll
        String nuovaz=x.replaceAll("i", "!");
        String nuova2z=nuovaz.replaceAll("s", "$");
        String nuova3z=nuova2.replaceAll("e", "&");
        System.out.println(nuova3z);


    }

}
```

Comment: `String nuova3z=nuova2.replaceAll("e", "&");` there is a mistake, `nuova2` should be `nuova2z`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`replaceAll` works with regular expressions. In the `replacAll` method, `$` is a reserved character used to reference groups defined in the regular expression given as first parameter, so you need to escape it.

```
String nuova2z=nuovaz.replaceAll("s", "\\$");
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/K0XmKf)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape characters which are use in regular expression, try following:

```
String nuovaz=x.replaceAll("i", "!");
String nuova2z=nuovaz.replaceAll("s", "\\$");
```